# How to check if worksheet exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a specific path's subfolders for an Excel book with a particular name. Once found, check if the document has a particular worksheet. If it doesn't, insert a sheet from another file and close the document.

I need to loop through every folder within a specific path (approx. 300 files in total).

```
Public strDestinationPath As String
Public strSearch As Variant    

Sub SearchFolders()

Range("B:M").ClearContents
Range("B1").Value = "Name"
Range("C1").Value = "Path"
Range("D1").Value = "Size (KB)"
Range("E1").Value = "DateLastModified"
Range("F1").Value = "Attributes"
Range("G1").Value = "DateCreated"
Range("H1").Value = "DateLastAccessed"
Range("I1").Value = "Drive"
Range("J1").Value = "ParentFolder"
Range("K1").Value = "ShortName"
Range("L1").Value = "ShortPath"
Range("M1").Value = "Type"
Range("B1").Select

Dim strPath As String
strPath = UserGetFolder & "\"

strSearch = InputBox("Enter Search Criteria (Case Sensitive)")

Dim OBJ As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object
Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder

If Range("B2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Files Found", vbInformation
Else
End If

Range("B1").Select

End Sub


Private Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

For Each File In Folder.Files

    If InStr(File.Name, strSearch) <> 0 Then
    
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = File.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = (File.Size / 1024) 'IN KB
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = File.DateLastModified
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = File.Attributes
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = File.DateCreated
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = File.DateLastAccessed
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = File.Drive
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = File.ParentFolder
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = File.ShortName
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = File.ShortPath
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = File.Type
        
    Else
    End If
    
Next File

End Sub


Private Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object

For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
    
    If File = Survey_Additional_Info Then
        Call WorksheetExists
        Call CopySheetToClosedWB
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
    
Next FolderItem

End Sub


Function UserGetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    UserGetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function


Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
    'Code to find sheet in a file - added by me not part of original

    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In closedBook.Worksheets
        If Application.Proper(Time_Slots) = Application.Proper(Time_Slots) Then
            WorksheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        Else: Call CopySheetToClosedWB
            
        End If
    Next Sht
    WorksheetExists = False
End Function


Sub CopySheetToClosedWB() 'Copy Worksheet to a Closed Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("S:\Accordant\SUS\NewTimeSlotTab.xlsx")
    Sheets("Time_Slots").Copy Before:=closedBook.Sheets(Alternative_Locations)
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My code works up to

```
Call WorksheetExists
```

Comment: You cannot call a `Boolean` `Function` like that. A `Boolean` function returns true or false. You need to write an `If` statement, ie. if boolean function = true then..

Answer (score 0):

The function `WorksheetExists()` has no idea what the variable *closedBook* is.  That variable is not passed nor is it Publlic.

**EDIT#1:**

In general, you cannot use a variable until you have assigned a value to it.

For example before the line:

```
For Each Sht In closedBook.Worksheets
```

There should be a **Dim** statement for `closedBook` and a **Set** statement as well.

The **Dim** and **Set** should be placed within the function containing the **For**.

Comment: any idea what it should be?

Comment: @oturk17 See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thank you, i have made some changes and now the code runs but is ignoring the insertion of the tab into all excel documents, guess ill have to keep playing around with it - i am only 3 weeks into writing code for the first time so appreciate the help.